# Android Device Monitor showing my device but not my project

Tags: android, debugging

I can't debug my App crash cause Android Device Monitor is not showing my project and consequently not showing the process ID causing the crash.

I can't post images here yet so here's a link to a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDutF.png

Note: This is a part of a debugging lesson in Udacity's Android Course, the tutorial shows Android Device Monitor displaying the app package below the device with the process ID. The tutorial screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOelA.png